# How to pass the parameter to an api using http POST method

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm using HTTP POST method to post a parameter but it is showing a 404 error. The same API is working fine in command line

My code is :

```
var dataToPost = {url:'http://google.com'}; 

    $http.post("http://appfil.es" , dataToPost)

        .success(function(serverResponse, status, headers, config) {

        })
        .error(function(serverResponse, status, headers, config) {

        }
    );
```

The above code returns error with status 404.. but the below code works fine is console.

```
curl -X POST http://appfil.es --data "url=http://google.com"..
```

Please help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your Web API code ?

Comment: var dataToPost = {url:'http://google.com'}; 
             
   alert(JSON.stringify(dataToPost));

  $http.post("http://appfil.es" , dataToPost)
    
            .success(function(serverResponse, status, headers, config) {
               
               alert(serverResponse);
               $ionicLoading.hide();
            })
            .error(function(serverResponse, status, headers, config) {
                alert(status);
                alert(JSON.stringify(config));
                 $ionicLoading.hide();
                 
            }
        );

Comment: Does this site support CORS? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: This looks like a CORS issue. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190207/jquery-ajax-call-to-cross-domain-returns-status-404-even-though-i-can-see-json-p

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct.

However, you can't make a `post` call across websites from a client's browser (XSS security)

Either ensure that `http://appfil.es` is the same url as the one of the web page containing your angular code or prefer using [$http.jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp).

More info on JSONP [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

You won't be able to shorten URLs from `appfil.es` as long as they don't send the following header from their API

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

Indeed, if you print the headers returned by `appfil.es` by adding option `-v` to your command, you only see:

```
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
* Server nginx/1.4.4 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.4
< Date: Mon, 29 Dec 2014 10:52:21 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 23
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://appfil.es/YVcCEA
```

Thus, no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. You can call their API from your website, server-side, not client (browser) side.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using AngularJs, you can use this transformer to encode your data, which will centralize the encoding for all your requests:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Module name is handy for logging
    var id = 'app';
    // Create the module and define its dependencies.
    var app = angular.module('app', [
    ]);
    app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        // Use x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
        // Override $http service's default transformRequest
        $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function (data) {
            /**
             * The workhorse; converts an object to x-www-form-urlencoded serialization.
             * @param {Object} obj
             * @return {String}
             */
            var param = function (obj) {
                var query = '';
                var name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i;
                for (name in obj) {
                    value = obj[name];
                    if (value instanceof Array) {
                        for (i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
                            subValue = value[i];
                            fullSubName = name + '[' + i + ']';
                            innerObj = {};
                            innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                            query += param(innerObj) + '&';
                        }
                    }
                    else if (value instanceof Object) {
                        for (subName in value) {
                            subValue = value[subName];
                            fullSubName = name + '[' + subName + ']';
                            innerObj = {};
                            innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                            query += param(innerObj) + '&';
                        }
                    }
                    else if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
                        query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&';
                    }
                }
                return query.length ? query.substr(0, query.length - 1) : query;
            };
            return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? param(data) : data;
        }];
    }]);

})();
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass the cURL request thru PHP inside the JavaScript variable.

```
    var dataToPost = <?php
    $ch = curl_init("http://www.google.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

Document.write(dataToPost); will give you the webpage of Google.com